# C# Updating an object when an object in its constructor changes

Tags: c#, oop, reference

I'm not sure how to ask this question in an elegant fashion, so here. I have this class that takes in an instance of a class AbilityScores in its constructor. I am wondering if there is some way to make it so that if the instance of AbilityScores that was passed in is updated it will update the instance of Skills automatically, or even better if it doesn't have to update the instance of Skills and just updates the property abilityScores in Skills.

It probably has something to do with referencing it instead of copying it in like I'm doing here, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

```
class Skills
{
    AbilityScores abilityScores;
    List<SkillChecks> skillProficiencies;
    List<SkillChecks> skillExpertices;
    LevelAndLevelRelatedBonuses level;

    public Skills(AbilityScores abilityScores, List<SkillChecks> skillProficiencies, List<SkillChecks> skillExpertices, LevelAndLevelRelatedBonuses level)
    {
        this.abilityScores = abilityScores;
        this.skillProficiencies = skillProficiencies;
        this.skillExpertices = skillExpertices;
        this.level = level;
    }

    //Insert other methods here (not important at the moment)
}
```

Comment: Unless `AbilityScores` is a struct then you _are_ referencing it, not copying it.  Classes are reference types so you have a _reference_ to an `AbilityScores` object in `Skills`.

Comment: `"if it doesn't have to update the instance of Skills and just updates the property abilityScores in Skills"` - This is where you confused me.  Can you describe specifically the behavior you're seeing, how it's incorrect, and show code which produces that behavior?

Comment: You are referencing it.  Whenever in doubt about if you are referencing the same instance of something, use the ".GetHashCode" method and compare them.

Comment: @Jay Actually `ReferenceEquals` should be used to see if the references are equal since `GetHashCode` can be overridden.

Comment: @DStanley you're right..

Comment: OP, are you saying that when some property of an `AbilityScores` instance changes, you want another class to be able to be notified about that? A simple solution would be to have `AbilityScores` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and have each `Skills` subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the instance of `AbilityScores` that it gets.

Comment: Normally, "abilityScores" is passed by referenced as mentioned by D. Stanley. Therefore, if a property of this object changes, "this.abilityScores" will also change as it refers to the same object, but I guess that's not what you're asking, because if so, you already did what you wanted :-D

Comment: Thank you D Stanley and Jay. I hadn't realized that it was already doing what I wanted it to do. Whoopsie. The ReferenceEquals function will be very helpful. Thanks again

Comment: Although stephen.vakil answer is correct, I think it is not a good idea to keep a reference of an object in different places. I suggest you to simply add a public property to your class and use that as your main reference.

Comment: @Saeid It's perfectly normal to have multiple references to an object.  Many data structures require it.  Without multiple references, you can't accomplish Dependency Injection as easily or elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is how object references work by default, assuming `AbilityScores` is a class.  Your `Skills` class has a *reference* to that `AbilityScores` instance.  If something else has that reference and acts upon the class, since you have the same reference to it, it will be updated.

From [c# documentation on reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx):

> there are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types. Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data. With reference types, two variables can reference the same object; therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable. With value types, each variable has its own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one variable to affect the other (except in the case of ref and out parameter variables, see ref (C# Reference) and out parameter modifier (C# Reference)).
>
> The following keywords are used to declare reference types:
>   class
>   interface
>   delegate

Assuming something strange isn't going on, this should happen by default.  See [this dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sB2eEI)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var scores = new AbilityScores() { Speed = 1, Durability = 1 };
        var skills = new Skills(scores);

        Console.WriteLine("Before change: " + skills.GetCurrentScores());

        scores.Speed = 2;
        scores.Durability = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("After change: " + skills.GetCurrentScores());

    }

}

public class Skills
{
    public AbilityScores abilityScores;

    public Skills(AbilityScores abilityScores)
    {
        this.abilityScores = abilityScores;
    }

    public string GetCurrentScores()
    {
        return "Speed: " + abilityScores.Speed + ", Durability: " + abilityScores.Durability;
    }


}

public class AbilityScores
{
    public int Speed {get; set;}
    public int Durability {get; set;}
}
```

Output:

```
Before change: Speed: 1, Durability: 1
After change: Speed: 2, Durability: 0
```

Comment: How to update scores value with skills object instead of  scores obj?